# Harvard citation in LyX gives "author?" or "year?", using bibDesk

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, harvard-style, bibdesk

Hi and thanks for excellent forum!

I am attempting to use bibDesk with LyX. I save the file in bibDesk (text encoding Unicode UTF-8), import it in lyx with style plain, and change the bibliography style to natbib.

For the citations I then have a numerous alternatives of the from (Author, year), "author, year", etc.

However when generating the pdf the citations gives me the following output:

option Mulazzani et al. (2013): output (author?)[1]

option (Mulazzani et al. 2013): output [1]

option Mulazzani et al. 2013: output (author?) 1

option Mulazzani et al., 2013: output 1

option Mulazzani et al.: output (author?)

option 2013: output (year?)

option (2013): output [(year?)]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Bibtex, the bibliography processor invoked by LyX, can't use utf8 - you'll have to save as ascii (latex ascii). It's always a good idea to check Document>LaTeX log>Log type Bibtex for errors. You could use biblatex and biber with your utf8 bibliography database, but that requires some more work: try the examples from this link https://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex